# How to move validation of user's input from Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I want to validate the maximum number of teams a user can submit to my web application.
I added  `int counting = 0;` to my `SubmitController` and added it to Post method of my Controller so it can increase when a user submits a new team.:

```
public class SubmitController {

    int counting = 0;

    private final SubmitRepo submitRepo;
    private final SubmitService submitService;

    @Autowired
    public SubmitController(SubmitRepo submitRepo, SubmitService submitService) {
        this.submitRepo = submitRepo;
        this.submitService = submitService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showSubmit (Model model) {
        return findPaginated(1, "id", "asc", model);
    }

    @GetMapping("/submit")
    public String showForm (Model model) {
        Submit submit = new Submit();
        model.addAttribute("submit", submit);
        List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
        model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
        return "submit_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submitForm (@Valid @ModelAttribute("submit") Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (counting>=4) {
            return "submit_max";
        }

        else if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
            model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
            return "submit_form";
        } else {
            submitRepo.save(submit);
            counting++;
            return "submit_ok";
        }
    }

@GetMapping("/list/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                @RequestParam("sortField") String sortField,
                                @RequestParam("sortDir") String sortDir,
                                Model model) {

        int pageSize = 10;
        Page<Submit> page = submitService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        List<Submit> submits = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalElements", page.getTotalElements());
        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        model.addAttribute("submits", submits);
        return "submit_list";
    }
//...
```

so there can be 4 teams submitted in this web application. Functionally this works well but has 2 issues:

1. The Controller should be clean without some validation logic with ints.
2. Every time I restart the app, my `int counting` equals to 0, but submitted teams in database remain, next time it can be 8 teams, then 12 etc...

I want to make the validation properly that in this web app can be max 4 teams submitted.
I thought about `@Size` annotation but I don't know how can I connect it with my code.

Submit:

```
@Entity
public class Submit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your team name")
    private String name;

    private String rank;
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter a nickname of team leader")
    private String leader;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "Integer default 0")
    private Integer score = 0;
    private Integer wins = 0;
    private Integer loses = 0;
    private Integer draws = 0;
```

SubmitService

```
@Service
public class SubmitService {

    private SubmitRepo submitRepo;

    @Autowired
    public SubmitService(SubmitRepo submitRepo) {
        this.submitRepo = submitRepo;
    }

    public Page<Submit> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
        Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
                Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo -1, pageSize, sort);
        return this.submitRepo.findAll(pageable);
     }
```

Comment: Is you submit controller somehow session scoped? It is singleton otherwise and wyou will end up with allowing only N entries in total beeing added by any user

Comment: No, it isn't. I want to storage max 4 teams submitted as it is now, but not by doing int variable in controller.